# OAuthException when trying to upload/post photos to group

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, photo-upload

I am currently trying to upload photos to pages and groups through an app. I have these codes:

```
try
{
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $args = array('message' => 'This is my image caption',); 
    $args['image'] = '@'.realpath('./uploads/terragarden1.png');
    $response = $facebook->api('/GROUP_ID/photos/','POST',$args);
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
{
     echo "Error: ".$e; 
}
```

The value of `$args['image']` would be something like this:

```
@/home/publica/public_html/AutoPost/uploads/terragarden1.png
```

The problem is that it throws an `OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred.` I don't quite know what to do with this kind of error.

Additional:
When I try to post image using the same code and just changing
`$response = $facebook->api('/GROUP_ID/photos/','POST',$args);`

into `$response = $facebook->api('/me/photos/','POST',$args);`, the image would successfully be posted on the user's wall. What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on pages:

```
$attachements = array(                                  
        'access_token' => $page->getToken(),
        'message' => $post_pub['title'],
        'url' => 'http://site.com/images/your_image.png' );                             
        try{
           $result = $facebook->api('/'.$page->getIdFacebook().'/photos', 'POST', $attachements, function(){
           }); 
        }
        catch(Exception $e){ }
```

Might want to try switching from 'image' to 'url'

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue.

There is a topic about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1430985030446221?browse=external_tasks_search_results_527428908614f7c36099745

I've been tried to do this with js sdk, with the same error response.

Comment: Yes, i have also been subscribed to that in my quest for the solution. Currently its status has been changed to fixed, but my app still shows OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred.